# scp not able to resolve dns name

Tags: networking, dns, debian, osx-yosemite, vmware-fusion

**Question first:** Does anyone know why scp won't resolve the dns name wheezy to the ip address 192.168.164.144 while ping does?

**Explanation & Details second**:

While on OS Mavericks I could scp files from my terminal to my VMWare Fusion Debian instance just fine.  I just had to make sure that the ip address and machine name (wheezy) were in both the Debian /etc/hosts file and in the /etc/hosts file of my mac.

However after upgrading to Yosemite I can't scp files to my virtual host **using the domain name**.   I **CAN** scp files to the virtual machine if I specify the ip address.   So this works:

```
scp test_file.txt dan@192.168.165.144:~/
```

but this does not:

```
scp test_file.txt dan@wheezy:~/
```

This boggles my mind because the host "wheezy" pings just fine:

```
BASHdan@DanRauxa ~ >>ping wheezy
PING wheezy (192.168.165.144): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.165.144: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.335 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.165.144: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.337 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.165.144: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms
^C
--- wheezy ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 0.290/0.321/0.337/0.022 ms
```

and my /etc/hosts file is actually identical on both the Yosemite and Wheezy machine:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
192.168.165.1 DanRauxa
192.168.165.144 wheezy 
127.0.0.1       drupal-7-31.local
127.0.0.1       drupal8devprep.local
```

Does anyone know why scp won't resolve the dns name wheezy to the ip address 192.168.164.144 while ping does?

Many thanks.
-d-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `~/.ssh/config` to see if there is a *wheezy* host in there.

Also run the `scp` in verbose mode:

```
scp -v test_file.txt dan@wheezy:~/.
```

Might give you more information on where the failure is happening.

Comment: Right you are Mr Solo Ranger!   I had a hardcoded old (over a year ago) entry in my .ssh/config file that I had forgotten about. Many Thanks! That fixed it, once I un-hardcoded it!